# Forcing Google safesearch blocks android push notifications

Tags: networking, dns, android, notifications

I'm attempting to force using google safesearch at a network level in dnsmasq.  The following statement forces any dns query to google.com to redirect to the specified safesearch ip address.

`address=/google.com/216.239.38.120`

This works well.  Any time anyone pulls up a google search, through browser or phone, the safesearch option is selected.

However, and this is a big however, when this is enabled all Android push notifications that need to go through this gateway fail.

I have to surmise that the push notifications, which go out over ports 5228, 5229, and 5230 to a large possible block of IP addresses, must be looking up google.com over dns to find the most appropriate IP, and google apparently does not listen for push notification messages on the safesearch IP.  Is this true?

My plan for a workaround is to reroute the specific ports used for push notification that are heading to 216.239.38.120 so they go to an actual non-safesearch google IP, which right now, from my network, is 172.217.11.238.  This will be an iptables rule, which I'll implement using shorewall.

Is there a better approach to meeting both requirements of enabling safesearch on the network level, and maintaining push notification functionality?

Comment: Read the Help section to learn the topics that are on and off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
address=/www.google.com/216.239.38.120
```

Apparently, I only need to redirect the `www` subdomain in order to force safe search, not ALL the subdomains.  Also, note that there is another way to accomplish this in dnsmasq.conf, and it appears closer to Google's recommended method:

```
host-record=forcesafesearch.google.com,216.239.38.120
cname=www.google.com,forcesafesearch.google.com
```

Also, note that there are a lot of international domains that also need redirected, but as the methods and madness are the same as the standard domain, I felt they were unnecessary details for my question.

References:
[DnsMasq and Push Notifications](https://community.ui.com/questions/DnsMasq-and-Push-Notifications/6d1aabf1-19b2-45cb-8e1e-9aca03b512b1)

[Parental controls - Enforcing Google SafeSearch and Youtube Kids mode from DnsMasq on OpenWRT](https://spotlightcybersecurity.com/openwrt-dnsmasq-google-youtube-bing-filtering.html)